# Problema con la importación de clases en Python

Tags: python

soy nuevo en esto de Python y pues me surgió un problema que no se como solucionarlo,
el problema es el siguiente:
Hice una clase en un modulo para luego importarlo a otro:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Manager(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Yo nunca: The game")
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, sin embargo cuando la importo al modulo donde la voy a usar, me dice que no se puede importar, esto lo hago en Visual studio code

```py
from Manager import Manager

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Manager()`
    app.mainloop()
```

Pues ese es mi problema, espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, salud2.

Comment: cual es la estructura de tu proyecto?

Comment: Sin saber la estructura de tu proyecto ni exactamente por que "no se puede importar", lo que dire es pura adivinansa: recuerda que Manager (con mayuscula inicial) no es lo mismo que manager (en minuscula)

Comment: Copia el código publicado como un nuevo proyecto y ejecuta correctamente.